# Notes.app asks to verify a certificate each time I start it

Tags: notes.app

Every time I open Notes.app on El Capitan, I get a popup asking me to verify a certificate.

The certificate is about one of the websites I manage, but I don't get why it asks about it when I open such app...

I've tried marking the certificate as secure in the management panel but it still asks me about it each time.

How can I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Systems Preferences** > **Internet Accounts** select the account of the website you manage and disable the **Notes**.

Comment: No prob, can you please mark the question as answered?

Comment: Yup I was waiting the X minutes needed

Comment: Oh sorry! Didn't realize that!